# Attachment problem!

Tags: development, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-enterprise

I want to save attachments to a list, and i'm using the following code:

```
        SPSite site = new SPSite("http://knowitintranet:9797/");
        SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
        SPList list = web.Lists.TryGetList("Extern products");

        try
        {
            if (list != null)
            {

                SPListItem item = list.Items.Add();
                if (TextBox_Name.Text == string.Empty &&
                    TextBox_ProdNum.Text == string.Empty && 
                    TextBox_ListPrice.Text == string.Empty && 
                    TextBox_Color.Text == string.Empty &&
                    TextBox_MoreInfo.Text == string.Empty)
                {
                    Label_Exception.Text = "Please enter values!";
                    Label_Exception.Visible = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    item["Title"] = TextBox_Name.Text;
                    item["ProductNumber"] = TextBox_ProdNum.Text;
                    item["ListPrice"] = TextBox_ListPrice.Text;
                    item["Color"] = TextBox_Color.Text;
                    item["MoreInformation"] = TextBox_MoreInfo.Text;

                    if (FileUpload_Pic.PostedFile != null && FileUpload_Pic.HasFile)
                    {
                        Stream fStream = FileUpload_Pic.PostedFile.InputStream;
                        byte[] contents = new byte[fStream.Length];
                        fStream.Read(contents, 0, (int)fStream.Length);
                        fStream.Close();
                        fStream.Dispose();
                        SPAttachmentCollection attachments = item.Attachments;
                        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload_Pic.PostedFile.FileName);
                        attachments.Add(fileName, contents);
                        //listItem["Attached FileName"] = fileName; // store the name of the file in a column for future requirements
                    }

                    if (FileUpload_Doc.PostedFile != null && FileUpload_Doc.HasFile)
                    {
                        Stream fStream = FileUpload_Doc.PostedFile.InputStream;
                        byte[] contents = new byte[fStream.Length];
                        fStream.Read(contents, 0, (int)fStream.Length);
                        fStream.Close();
                        fStream.Dispose();
                        SPAttachmentCollection attachments = item.Attachments;
                        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload_Doc.PostedFile.FileName);
                        attachments.Add(fileName, contents);
                    }
                    item.Update();

                    //Rensar texboxarna
                    TextBox_Name.Text = string.Empty;
                    TextBox_ProdNum.Text = string.Empty;
                    TextBox_ListPrice.Text = string.Empty;
                    TextBox_Color.Text = string.Empty;
                    TextBox_MoreInfo.Text = string.Empty;
                    TextBox_Search.Text = string.Empty;

                    site.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Label_Exception.Text = "List doesn't exist!";
        }
```

Everything works fine, but it saves only one attachment (the fileUpload_pic) control.

Any suggestions?

/Kristian

Answer (score 1):

Try using `SPAttachmentCollection.AddNow()` instead of `SPAttachmentCollection.Add()`.